# Prove that $(f \circ g)^{(n)}$ exists for any n

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose two functions $g,f$ such that $g$ is $n$ times differentiable in $a$ and $f$ is $n$ times differentiable in $g(a)$. Prove that $(f \circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists for any value of $n$.

Spivak hints that the $n$-th derivative of $f \circ g$ is a sum of terms of some structure, but the only thing I've found is that the first term has the value of $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and the last one has the term $g^{(n)}(a)$, besides that I didn't found anything useful. Hope anybody could help me.

Comment: At best you can prove that $f \circ g$ is $n$ times differentiable. To see this take some $g$ that is $n$ times differentiable but not $n+1$ times differentiable and let $f$ be the identify.

Comment: That would give me just a case where this is true. I need a general proof about it.

Comment: My point was that your statement is incorrect (or at least ambiguous).

Comment: Which Spivak is this? Regular Calculus or Manifolds?

Comment: Wording can be quite important in mathematics: When you say “prove that … for any value of $n$” you are asking for a proof of a statement of the form “for all $n$, …”. But that makes no sense here, since $n$ is implicitly already given a fixed (but unknown) value in the first sentence, so it is no longer free to vary. If the second sentence went “prove that … no matter what the value of $n$ is”, it would be better, since you are not really invoking the dreaded ∀ quantifier.

Comment: @alonso s Regular calculus

Comment: To add to my previous comment: It is better because “no matter what …” is more easily recognised as informal language rather than having mathematical content. But you might just as well drop the entire phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\phi$ is differentiable, then the derivative $\phi'$ exists.

If $\phi$ is $n>1$ times differentiable, then $\phi'$ is $n-1$ times differentiable.

If $f,g$ are differentiable, then $f \circ g$ is differentiable and $(f \circ g)' = (f' \circ g) \cdot g'$.

If $f,g$ are $n>1$ times differentiable, then since $f',g'$ are $n-1$ times differentiable, it follows that $(f \circ g)'$ is $n-1$ times differentiable.

The result follows by induction.

Comment: I believe that $(f\circ g)$ is meant as composition and not product in this context.

Comment: @alonso s indeed it means composition

Comment: @alonsos: Thanks for catching that, I was asleep at the wheel. I have the correct composition rule there now...

Comment: Thanks for the correction, this seems easier than the previous idea.