# Spivak Chapter 10, Exercise 19 solution verification. Prove that if $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, induction, chain-rule

This question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003736/prove-that-f-circ-gn-exists-for-any-n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258517/spivak-chapter-10-problem-19).

I'm going to try to answer it for my own edification, and for the next poor soul that comes across it and has trouble :)

I'm using Spivak's Answer Book solution, but adding notes to hopefully clarify things.

Here goes:

From Calculus by Michael Spivak 3rd Edition, Chapter 10, Exercise 19.

> 10-19. Prove that if $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists. A little experimentation should convince you that it is unwise to seek a formula for $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$. In order to prove that $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists you will therefore have to devise a reasonable assertion about $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ which can be proved by induction. Try something like: "$(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists and is a sum of terms each of which is a product of terms of the form..."

First, let's look at the first few derivatives of $(f\circ g)$. (These are calculated via straightforward application of the Chain Rule):

$$(f\circ g)^{\prime}(x) = f^{\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime}(x)$$
$$(f\circ g)^{\prime\prime}(x) = f^{\prime\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime}(x)^2 + f^{\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime\prime}(x)$$
$$(f\circ g)^{\prime\prime\prime}(x) = f^{\prime\prime\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime}(x)^3 + 3f^{\prime\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime}(x)g^{\prime\prime}(x) + f^{\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)$$

These suggest a general form for derivatives of $(f\circ g)$: the $n$-th derivative of $f\circ g$ seems to be made up of a sum of terms that are each the product of some constant, times some derivative of $f$ at $g(x)$, times some derivatives of $g$ at $x$, with these derivatives of $g$ perhaps raised to some power. None of the derivatives (of $f$ or $g$) are of order higher than $n$.

**Conjecture: If $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists and is a sum of terms of the form
$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(a)]^{m_1}\cdot[g^{\prime\prime}(a)]^{m_2}\cdots[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n}\cdot f^{(k)}(g(a))$$
for some number $c$, nonnegative integers $m_1,\dots,m_n$ and a natural number $k \leq n$.**

(Aside: The conjecture concerns the existence of the derivative *at a single point*, $a$. It says, "if $g$ is $n$-times differentiable at $a$ and $f$ is $n$-times differentiable at $g(a)$, then $f\circ g$ is $n$-times differentiable at $a$. If there's a second point $b$ such that $g$ is $n$-times differentiable at $b$ and $f$ is $n$-times differentiable at $g(b)$, then $f\circ g$ is $n$-times differentiable at $b$, and $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(b)$ is the sum of terms of the form
$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(b)]^{m_1}\cdot[g^{\prime\prime}(b)]^{m_2}\cdots[g^{(n)}(b)]^{m_n}\cdot f^{(k)}(g(b))$$

where $c$, $m_1, \dots, m_n$, $k$ in each term are all identical to the corresponding term for $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$.)

**Proof:**
Let's restate the conjecture we're trying to prove.

Conjecture:
If $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists and is a sum of terms of the form

$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(a)]^{m_1}\cdot[g^{\prime\prime}(a)]^{m_2}\cdots[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n}\cdot f^{(k)}(g(a))$$

Proof of the conjecture is by induction on $n$

*Case for $n = 1$*

If $f^{\prime}(g(a))$ and $g^{\prime}(a)$ both exist, then the Chain rule states that $(f\circ g)^{\prime}(a)$ exists and is equal to $f^{\prime}(g(a)) \cdot g^{\prime}(a)$.

Thus our conjecture is true for $n = 1$ (with $c = m_1 = k = 1$).

*Case for $n + 1$*

We will assume the conjecture is true for $n$, that is, *if* $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists and is a sum of terms of the form
$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(a)]^{m_1}\cdot[g^{\prime\prime}(a)]^{m_2}\cdots[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n}\cdot f^{(k)}(g(a))$$

Note that we are *not* assuming that $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists. Our assumption is that ***if*** $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, ***then*** $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists.

(This distinction is important and sets this proof apart from inductive arguments I've previously encountered. Our assumption isn't simply "thing is true". Our assumption is that "*if* this condition is met, thing is true." This is in agreement with the theorem we're trying to prove. The theorem doesn't say the $n$-th derivative of $f\circ g$ exists. Only that, *if* certain conditions are met, the derivative exists.)

Now we need to prove the conjecture for the $n + 1$ case. We need to show that *if* $f^{(n+1)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n+1)}(a)$ both exist, *then* $(f\circ g)^{(n+1)}(a)$ exists, and is a sum of terms of the form

$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(a)]^{m_1}\cdots[g^{(n+1)}(a)]^{m_{n+1}}\cdot f^{(k)}(g(a))$$

with $k \leq n+1$.

Suppose $f^{(n+1)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n+1)}(a)$ both exist.

This means that $f^{(n)}(y)$ exists for all $y$ in some interval around $g(a)$, and likewise $g^{(n)}(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some interval around $a$. Why? Because, by definition the $(n+1)$ derivatives are

$$f^{(n+1)}(g(a)) = \lim_{y \to g(a)}\frac{f^{(n)}(y) - f^{(n)}(g(a))}{y-g(a)}$$
$$g^{(n+1)}(a) = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{g^{(n)}(x) - g^{(n)}(a)}{x-a}$$

and in order for these limits to exist, the $n$-order derivatives *must* exist in some intervals around these points.

Furthermore, $f^{(k)}$ and $g^{(k)}$ must also exist in these intervals for all $1\leq k < n$.

Because $f^{(n)}$ exists at and around $g(a)$, there is some $\varepsilon_f > 0$ such that for all $y$ if $|y - g(a)| < \varepsilon_f$, $f^{(n)}(y)$ exists. Likewise, since  $g^{(n)}$ exists at and around $a$ there is some $\delta_g >0$ such that for all $x$ if $|x-a| < \delta_g$, $g^{(n)}(x)$ exists.

We know that $g$ is continuous at $a$ (it's differentiable). As such there exists some $\delta_f > 0$ such that for all $x$ if $|x-a| < \delta_f$, then $|g(x) - g(a)| < \varepsilon_f$. If we use $\delta_{min} = \min(\delta_g,\delta_f)$ then for all $x$ if $|x-a| < \delta_{min}$, both $g^{(n)}(x)$ and $f^{(n)}(g(x))$ will exist.

In this interval both $g^{(n)}(x)$ and $f^{(n)}(g(x))$ exist, so the $n$-case assumption tells us $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(x)$ exists and is a sum of terms of the form

$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(x)]^{m_1}\cdot[g^{\prime\prime}(x)]^{m_2}\cdots[g^{(n)}(x)]^{m_n}\cdot f^{(k)}(g(x))$$

Worth noting: we're no longer only talking about the value of $(f\circ g)^{(n)}$ at a single point $a$. $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(x)$ exists *for all* $x$ in this interval around $a$.

$(f\circ g)^{(n)}$ is a *function* that's defined at and around $a$. Furthermore, $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(x)$ is the sum of products of constants and derivatives of $f$ and $g$ and these derivatives are all themselves differentiable at $a$

Therefore, the derivative of $(f\circ g)^{(n)}$ at $a$ exists and can be calculated using the standard, sum, product and chain rules for derivatives.

Doing so will result in terms that look like either this

$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(a)]^{m_1}\cdots m_{\alpha}[g^{(\alpha)}(a)]^{m_{\alpha}-1}\cdot[g^{(\alpha+1)}(a)]^{m_{\alpha+1}+1}\cdots[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n}\cdot f^{(k)}(g(a))$$

this

$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(a)]^{m_1}\cdots m_n[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n-1}\cdot[g^{(n+1)}(a)]\cdot f^{(k)}(g(a))$$

or this

$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(a)]^{m_1+1}\cdots[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n}\cdot f^{(k+1)}(g(a))$$

all of which fit the required form for terms of the $n+1$ case.

Therefore, if $f^{(n+1)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n+1)}(a)$ both exist, *then* $((f\circ g)^{(n)})^{\prime}(a) = (f\circ g)^{(n+1)}(a)$ exists, and is a sum of terms of the form

$$c\cdot[g^{\prime}(a)]^{m_1}\cdots[g^{(n+1)}(a)]^{m_{n+1}}\cdot f^{(k)}(g(a))$$

with $k \leq n+1$.

This completes the proof.
I hope.

Comment: You might be right (I haven't taken a full look at your proof) but I think this is really the "wrong" way of going about using induction, and this is one of the few exercises in Spivak where I found his suggestion not helpful. The simplest way I think is the way it's done in one of the linked posts. Having said this, I think from time to time, it is worth doing things the long-winded way just so you can appreciate the more efficient proof :)

Comment: I hope you're right. Always happy to have a better solution. I'm not sure the answers in those linked questions address the fact that the problem specifies the existence of $g^{(n))(a) and $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ at $a$ and $g(a)$ only. This seems important.

Comment: the way it (the proof in first link) is worded may give you the impression that the solution assumes more than just existence of nth derivative at the respective points, but a careful reading of the proof shows that it actually doesn't assume anything extra.

Comment: tbh I'm not sure I follow that proof. It seems to take for granted some of what it's supposed to be proving. I do like the trick of concluding what's meant to be an inductive proof by saying "The result follows by induction" :) I think it's just too smart for me.

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad I tried it as it underlined to me the distinction between the value of the derivative at a point and the derivative as a differentiable function. Before all this, if you'd told me "$f^{\prime}(a) = 3a^2$, where $a$ is a single point. Find $f^{\prime\prime}$ at $a$," I would probably answer $6a$ without thinking about it.

Comment: What you discovered is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: Cool! I can't say I really *discovered* it though, as a) my terms are more generally defined and b) I stole them from Spivak. This was really an attempt to flesh out the vaguer parts of the published solution. I may have succeeded only in lengthening it and making it more confusing :)